# Use instance name instead of instance ID in GCP custom chart

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I am creating a custom dashboard in GCP and instead of the instance name being used in the table, its using the instance id which can be confusing.

Is there was way to replace the instance id with the instance name ?

[image]

Options to change values. There is no instance_name here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There should be a button you can press next to "Value". Click on the button and do the following:

1.Uncheck the box titled "Name (from instance_id)"
2. Check the box titled "instance_name"

This will get rid of the  "Name (from instance_id)" and add a field "instance name" which will show the names of the instances.

Comment: Unfortunately the only options I have there are Name (from instance_id), instance_id, zone, state and project_id. There is no option of instance_name :( . Adding the screenshot to the original post

Comment: I would sugguest to create an issue on [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187228&template=0) as this does not seem to be expected behavior.